# I need to capture Text from webpage

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, gettext

below is HTML code present in DOM

`<center> "1 file " <br> "has been successfully uploaded." </center>`

I have to return text "has been successfully uploaded." in my method.
tried using getText() and getAttribute("innerHTML") methods but it is printing null.
is there other workarounds to fetch the text?

Answer (score 0):

This piece of JavaScript extracts what you want:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('center')[0].childNodes[2]
```

If you have more `center` elements you have to modify the code to select the right node.